# How to preload sound and play it in Java simply?

Tags: java, audio, javasound, clip

How to preload sound an play it in java from time to time? I found example including `Clip.open(AudioInputStream)` method but nowadays API has no one.

I know I can open `AudioInputStream` and `SourceDataLine` and copy data from one to other but is there any simpler method?

Answer (score 0):

Clip is for preloading into memory. SourceDataLine is for sounds that are too large to hold in memory.

You preload the Clip with the "open" method.

When you are ready to play it, you use the "start" method.
After playing it (or before playing it again) you need to reposition back to the start of the Clip.

Here is the official tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html